# Python subprocess.call non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, subprocess, imagemagick-convert

I'm attempting to use subprocess to call the Image Magick convert function, but I keep getting errors. When I make the python statements

```
x = '/usr/local/bin/convert -density 600 /path/to/myFile.pdf -depth 8 -delete 0,1,2,6,9 -strip -background white -alpha off /path/to/myTiff.tiff'
result = subprocess.check_output(x.split())
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    result = subprocess.check_output(x.split())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
**kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command "['/usr/local/bin/convert', '-density', '600', '/path/to/myFile.pdf', '-depth', '8', '-delete', '0,1,2,5,6,9', '-strip', '-background', 'white', '-alpha', 'off', '/path/to/myTiff.tiff']" returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

However, if I add `shell=True`, then I don't get errors anymore, but I also don't get the .tiff file, either. I'm wondering why I get errors without adding `shell=True`, and also why I'm still not getting the desired .tiff file.

Comment: Do you run the script in a terminal so that you would receive possible messages sent to stderr?

Comment: You replaced your paths in your example it seems.  Are your paths by chance something other than simple absolute paths?  If you have "~" or variable or command expansions in any of your paths, that would explain it.  That's stuff dealt with by a shell.  Without the shell, that stuff wouldn't get converted to the real path you want to work with.  Just a stab in the dark.  Looking at your question, I can't think of any other reason that the behavior would change with `shell=True`.

Comment: Have you tried not splitting `x` and setting `shell=True`? That's what I'd probably be doing here.  If you've already got a command in a string, why not just pass the string through a shell and let it pull apart the command arguments.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I took the commands straight from terminal, which is also why I was confused.

Comment: @Steve I first used relative paths, and then I tried absolute paths, which didn't appear to help. When I use ``shell=True`` with what I have, I don't get the errors, but I didn't get the desired .tiff file. If I submit the unsplit string with ``shell=True``, I get an exit code of 127.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to confirm exactly what command you're actually running.  Write a stand-in script that just echos its parameter and you'll know.  I've done what you're doing from Python literally 100s of times.  I'm guessing it's something about the environment you're running the command into.

Comment: @Steve For interest, I wanted to see what would happen if I stripped out all of the other parts, so I ran ``subprocess.call('/usr/local/bin/convert /path/to/myPDF.pdf /path/to/myTIFF.tiff'.split())`` and still wound up with the exit status "1", but if I copy-paste the command into Terminal, it runs and I get the desired output. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be with your convert command, not your python.

Remove the -delete argument, and it runs fine for me unmodified. I obviously don't have your input files to check, but I think the indexes you're specifying don't exist. When passing invalid items to -delete, convert does exit 1, so I'm willing to bet this is your issue.

Comment: Very strange. When running from terminal, I have no problems at all with the ``-delete`` command (and the .tiff is also created). The reason for using delete is that I'm only concerned with 4-5 pages in 10-12 page files. Now, even after removing that argument, I still get the exit status "1" without ``shell=True``, and "0" with ``shell=True``, but the .tiff was still not generated.

Comment: For interest, I wanted to see what would happen if I stripped out all of the other parts, so I ran ``subprocess.call('/usr/local/bin/convert /path/to/myPDF.pdf /path/to/myTIFF.tiff'.split())`` and still wound up with the exit status "1", but if I copy-paste the command into Terminal, it runs and I get the desired output. Very strange.